# EE Error: "Unable to Load Site Preferences; No Preferences Found"

Tags: database-error

I'm getting this error and can't understand why. This is for a site that I've reset the hosting to it's default state and have uploaded the site files and database to a basically new installation. It works 100% on the local environment.

I've read the threads here and have checked my permissions on config.php and database.php. I've also triple checked all of the database credentials and I still can't figure out what's going on. The host is saying there is nothing wrong and we can access the DB just fine through phpmyadmin. What else am I missing?

Please help!

Comment: Can you connect through phpmyadmin using exactly the same username/password (copy pasted) in your `config/database.php` file? What do you have the `hostname` parameter set as? Sometimes changing the `hostname` parameter from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` helps.

Answer (score 3):

This is often caused from incorrect DB credentials.  If you set debug="2" in your config file, do you get any additional errors?